# Mounted Combat and Sneak Attack

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, mounted-combat

Would a halfling rogue mounted on a War Dog get to apply sneak attack damage to a melee attack made while mounted?

The Sneak Attack text states "You don't need advantage on the attack roll if another enemy of the target is within 5 feet of it, that enemy isn't incapacitated, and you don't have disadvantage on the attack roll."

But, a controlled mount does not attack, it's only actions are Dash, Disengage, or Dodge.  Does this remove the mount as "...another enemy of the target..."?

I'm inclined to allow Sneak Attack for a rogue mounted on a trained mount, but wanted to know if there is any official ruling on this topic.

Comment: thank you Purple Monkey, i did not find that question due to my poor searching

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. And no worries! That's why leaving duplicate questions up helps; it serves as a signpost to help future readers find the existing question.